# Finding how many characters given in list are in list of n strings?

Tags: python, list

I have these two lists

```
['lfhtzrxcj', 'fbtzlhrcj', 'lzdaftrjphco']

['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'h', 'j', 'l', 'o', 'p', 'r', 't', 'x', 'z']
```

and I need to find how many of the letters in the second list are in all of the strings in the first list.

I have no idea how to make it...

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]. No input-output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Including what you have tried will have your post more well-received :)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the prettiest code, but it works:

```
def count_letters (letter_list, word_list):
    # creating a list of counters for each letter you want to count
    counter_list =[]
    i= 0
    for i in letter_list:
        counter_list.append(0)
    # counting how many times each letter is in a word
    for word in word_list:
        #print(word)
        i = 0
        for l in letter_list:
            counter_list[i]+=word.count(l)
            i=i+1
        #print(letter_list)
    print(counter_list)
    return counter_list
```

using your example:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'h', 'j', 'l', 'o', 'p', 'r', 't', 'x', 'z']
word_list = ['lfhtzrxcj', 'fbtzlhrcj', 'lzdaftrjphco']

count_letters(a,word_list)
```

You get the following output:

```
[1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3]
```